# Slowdown in 0.5 and 0.6?

Tags: performance, iteration, julia

I am updating my code from Julia 0.4 to 0.5 and I am encountering some slowdown. A simple example of what I am encountering is

```
x = rand(1:100, (50, 7, 3))

function f(a::Int, e::Int, r::Int)
    x[a-16+1, e-10+1, r]
end

y = sum(f(a, e, r) for a in 16:65, e in 10:16, r in 1:3) # in 0.5 and 0.6
y = sum([f(a, e, r) for a in 16:65, e in 10:16, r in 1:3]) # in 0.4
```

In 0.4 the last line (with list comprehension) takes 0.0004 seconds, while in 0.5 and 0.6 it takes around 0.1376. What is happening in versions 0.5 and 0.6?

Comment: How do you know it is a 0.5/0.6 slowdown rather than a list comprehension vs generator expression slow down?

Answer (score 10):

You're using non-constant globals and timing code in global scope. Make `x` constant (or pass it as a function argument) and put the `sum` computation in a function:

```
const x = rand(1:100, (50, 7, 3))

function f(a::Int, e::Int, r::Int)
    x[a-16+1, e-10+1, r]
end

g() = sum(f(a, e, r) for a in 16:65, e in 10:16, r in 1:3) # in 0.5 and 0.6
h() = sum([f(a, e, r) for a in 16:65, e in 10:16, r in 1:3]) # in 0.4
```

I see nearly exactly the same timings as you reported when I run your original code.  With the code as I've written:

0.6.0-pre.alpha.117:

```
julia> g(); @time g() # Call g() before timing it to compile it
  0.000020 seconds (9 allocations: 416 bytes)
53033

julia> h(); @time h()
  0.000026 seconds (6 allocations: 8.547 KiB)
53033
```

0.4.7:

```
julia> h(); @time h()
  0.000020 seconds (6 allocations: 8.453 KB)
50658
```

It's now so fast you can no longer precisely benchmark it with just one run.

Yes, 0.5 and 0.6 did get slower in your original case. This is because it now constructs a special function object for the comprehension/generator and compiles it. So when you run those statements at top-level, you're paying (and measuring) the compilation cost each time. When you put it in a function, Julia is able to compile it once and then every subsequent call is extremely fast. I highly recommend reading all the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/) if you're interested in optimizing performance. Avoiding globals is the very first section.

Comment: Suppose I scale up with `const x = rand(1:100, (50, 7, 3, 50, 7, 3))` and enclose the sum in a function like you do. The performance of 0.5 and 0.6 is significantly behind that of 0.4. I noticed however that summing with an explicit loop improves the performance... changing my project to loops will be tedious.

Comment: What versions are you using?  There was a regression with 6+ dimension arrays on 0.5.0 that has been fixed on 0.6-alpha and mostly-fixed on 0.5.1.

Comment: precisely those, 0.5.1 and 0.6-pre-alpha (last night's build). should i just wait for the release of 0.6?

Comment: btw, I'm using the mac versions.

Comment: That looks like a separate regression.  Issue filed: [#21058](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21058)

Comment: If you know the element type in advance you can use a typed comprehension: `sum(Int[f(…) for …])`.  That seems to step around the issue.